# how to add external jar file in freeswitch when we used mod_java

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, freeswitch

How to add spring jar files in `freeswitch` with java?

```
<configuration name="java.conf" description="Java Plug-Ins">
<javavm path="/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so"/>
<options>
<option value="-Djava.class.path=$${script_dir}/freeswitch.jar:$${script_dir}/"/>
<option value="-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=127.0.0.1:8000"/>
</options>
<startup class="EventLauncher" method="startup" arg=""/>
```